# SSH pub key (rsa_id.pub) does not work with MobaXterm but works with PowerShell and other apps

Tags: windows, ssh-keys, mobaxterm

I used PowerShell to create a SSH key like so:

```
ssh-keygen.exe
# Enter to accept all default + blank PW
# Saved in C:\users\me\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
```

I can SSH to my server via PowerShell and it works as expected: `ssh user@MyLinuxServer`

However, when I use MobaXterm it will not connect, even after specifying the id_rsa.pub key file:

```
No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you followed [this procedure](https://cinhtau.net/2016/02/03/use-ssh-keys-for-authentication-with-mobaxterm/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide MobaXterm with the **private** key, not the public key.  Typically this would be found in the same directory as the public key:

```
C:\users\me\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Comment: Welp, I feel dumb, lol. It was staring me in the face the whole time. Thank you!