# MobaXterm issue using Private Key for SSH access to Linux server (from Win11 workstation): "bin" folder is open in another program

Tags: windows-11, ssh-keys, mobaxterm

Issue seemed to start after adding my private key for the SSH session:

- [SSH pub key (rsa_id.pub) does not work with MobaXterm but works with PowerShell and other apps](https://superuser.com/questions/1775015/ssh-pub-key-rsa-id-pub-does-not-work-with-mobaxterm-but-works-with-powershell/1775016#1775016)

This happens whenever I start the connection. I think it's talking about one of the two the directories here:

- `C:\Users\myUser\Documents\MobaXterm\slash\bin`
- `C:\Users\myUser\OneDrive - myCompany\CompanyCorp\Documents\MobaXterm\slash\bin`

[image: MobaXterm_file-lock_issue]

Answer (score 0):

...looking at this I just found the issue. **OneDrive** was locking the directory. I excluded the parent directory from OneDrive sync and that fixed the issue.

- Open OneDrive settings (select the OneDrive cloud icon in your
  notification area, and then select the OneDrive Help and Settings
  icon then **Settings**.)
- Go to the Account tab.
- Select Choose folders.
- UNcheck `C:\Users\username\OneDrive - CompanyName\CompanyCorp\Documents\MobaXterm\`